# how to show column only when prior column has a specific value

Tags: html, angularjs, if-statement, ng-show, ng-hide

I am pulling data from database into a table.

A fraction of the table code is as below

```
<tr>
    <th>Approved</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in list">
    <td>
        <span data-ng-show="!editable">{{x.approved}}</span>
        <span data-ng-show="editable">
             <select style="" class="form-control" ng-model="x.approved">
                  <option value="Y">Y</option>
                  <option value="N">N</option>
             </select>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span type="submit" data-ng-hide="editable" data-ng-click="editable = true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        <span type="submit" data-ng-show="editable" data-ng-click="editable = false; change($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>
        <span type="submit" data-ng-show="editable" data-ng-click="editable = false; cancel()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Approved column gives either a 'Y' or a 'N'.
I have written the javascript code(change($index) functionality) at the backend to exchange values of Y and N on my necessity.

the second column shows an editable icon at all times for me to change values. I want it to show the editable icon only when {{x.approved}} == N so that i can change the approved status to Y.

I am not sure how or where to use the ng-show option.

Tried but not able to understand if ng-show='{{x.approved}}=="N"' works or not in the "td" element.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: ng-show='x.approved=="N"' No need for {{}} in ng- attributes

Comment: WOW! worked like a charm ..  thanks

Comment: Hello Gray. I have a new problem. Even though it works i keep seeing a blank css column in parts of the table because i am applying the ng-show in the "td" element. I need to have the td element at all times. So i need to include the ng-show in this line "<span type="submit" data-ng-hide="editable" data-ng-click="editable = true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>". any tips on how to do that? By this method, i wont have empty css lines in the table.

Comment: something along the lines of this "data-ng-hide='editable | x.approved=="N"'" or something like that .. since this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-show or ng-if to show,hide the element

```
<span type="submit" ng-if='x.approved=="N"' data-ng-click="editable = true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
```

Comment: i am trying to hide the edit icon depending on the value of approved .. not hiding the value of approved.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.Updated.Using ng-if removes the element from dom,whereas ng-show or ng-hide just change your css classes to make the element not to be visible to the user

Answer (score 0):

**FIRSTLY:** There is no issue with td element,It will work properly.

*Use without eval-expression as we are accesing in ng-elements*

```
ng-show='x.approved=="N"'
```

*Instead of*

```
ng-show='{{x.approved}}=="N"'
```

**Secondly**: Check your condition by ng-if, like

```
ng-if='x.approved=="N"'
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i have tried the above ng-if. i couldnt find the difference between it and ng-show. I have added the implementation i have used to get the answer. checking my answer would give you a better understanding of what i was trying to achieve. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Np Harsha, difference between them is : ng-if directive removes the content from the page & ng-show/ng-hide uses the css display property to hide content. so if you looked for css hide, its fine.

Comment: oh ok .. this is something new to me .. makes sense .. thanks, lokesh!

Comment: Hey Harsha, If make sense then upvote for my answer..thanks

Answer (score 0):

span type="submit" data-ng-hide="editable" data-ng-click="editable = true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">/span>

was replaced with

span type="submit" ng-show='x.approved=="N" && !editable' data-ng-click="editable = true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">/span>

I got the desired answer with the above implementation.
Thanks for the support!